# how to Asynchronous acquisition dom with vue3.2 + ts + element plus

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, element-plus

My template structure is

```
<el-form :model="form" ref="elementRef" class="form" :rules="rules">
<el-button class="login-btn" type="primary" @click="submit()">login</el-button>
```

setup part

```
 * @description: 
 * 
 * @param {*}
 * @return {*}
 * @author: 
 */
let elementRef = $ref(null)
const submit = (): void => {
  elementRef.validate(async (valid: boolean) => {
    if (valid) {
      data.loading = true
      let res = await user.login(form)
      if (res) router.push({ name: 'home' })
    }
  })
}
```

- Login form submission, submission is an asynchronous function,
- but elementRef does not get ts error will be reported
- The object may be null, but the project can be executed normally.

In what way can the error of ts be solved

Asking a question for the first time, thanks for your reply

Comment: "In what way can the error of ts be solved". What error do you get?

Comment: The question lacks clear problem statement, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask